# Make div height approximately constant and yet "responsive" as in airbnb

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML (http://jsfiddle.net/z0wgza3s/2):

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/2200x800" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="menu-all">
        <div class="menu">This is the menu</div>
        <div class="tools">These are the tools</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.header {
  position: relative;
}
.image {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1
}
#menu-all {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:2
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  outline: 0;
}
```

I am trying to replicate what Airbnb uses on their home page.

If you notice the height is always constant ...

When the browser width is increased the video is cropped on top ...

When the browser width is decreased the video is cropped on right.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```
<header>
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/2200x800" />
</div>
</header>
<div id="text-container">
   <div id="text-middle">           
      <h1>Test title</h1>
      <p>Test text, blah, blah</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

```
body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;}
#text-container {position: relative; height: 300px; width: 100%; text-align: center; display: table;}
#text-middle {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
#container {position: absolute; right: 0; left: 0; top: 0; overflow: hidden;
height: 300px; /*adjust height*/
min-width:  1000px; /* depends on img res.; change to 1px to see */
}
h1, p {font-family: Arial;}
img {bottom: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%;}
```

---

*Works fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE.*

Hope this helps to clear things up.